# Unity register instance of object from a viewmodel

Tags: .net, unity-container, prism

I have an application which connects to a hardware device via BLE.  There are several devices that have slightly different capabilities and I would like to register an instance of a device after the user selects it for connection.  This instance will be used by many other models later.  However, I don't have access to the Unity container in my viewmodel so I'm not sure of the correct way to do this.

Comment: Send a message to the part of the application that does have access?

Comment: @Draco18s no part of the (running) application should have access to the container, all container related stuff should happen when the application starts and no one even knows about the container after initialization is done.

Comment: Yes, I thought about keeping a private reference in the app and using the event aggregator to relay the instance and register is that way... but there has to be a better way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not want to manually interact with the container outside your composition root, because you do not want or need to tie your application to a specific container.

In your situation, you create an application-specific mini-container just for this use case:

```
public interface IDevice
{
    void DoStuff();
}

public interface IDeviceProvider
{
    IDevice ActiveDevice { get; set }
}

internal DeviceProvider : IServiceProvider
{
    public IDevice ActiveDevice { get; set; }
}

internal class Consumer
{
    public Consumer( IDeviceProvider deviceProvider )
    {
        _deviceProvider = deviceProvider;
    }

    public void UseDevice()
    {
        _deviceProvider.ActiveDevice?.DoStuff()??throw new Exception("No device connected");
    }

    private readonly IDeviceProvider _deviceProvider;
}
```

You can enhance this by separating setting the active device and reading the active device into two interfaces and/or restricting visibility of the setter-interface to certain modules, but it works fine without accessing or even having a container (you don't use the container in your tests anyway, do you?).

To actually create the devices, you do not need the container, too, as unity can inject e.g. `Func<DeviceA>` to create `DeviceA` instances when needed.